# Update a SavedQuery (View) from the SDK

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I am trying to change all the Business Unit references I got after importing a solution to the ones in the Acceptance environment.

```cs
QueryExpression ViewQuery = new QueryExpression("savedquery");
String[] viewArrayFields = { "name", "fetchxml" };

ViewQuery.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(viewArrayFields);


ViewQuery.PageInfo = new PagingInfo();
ViewQuery.PageInfo.Count = 5000;
ViewQuery.PageInfo.PageNumber = 1;
ViewQuery.PageInfo.ReturnTotalRecordCount = true;

EntityCollection retrievedViews = service.RetrieveMultiple(ViewQuery);
//iterate though the values and print the right one for the current user
int oldValues = 0;
int accValuesUpdated = 0;
int prodValuesUpdated = 0;
int total = 0;
foreach (var entity in retrievedViews.Entities)
{
    total++;
    if (!entity.Contains("fetchxml"))
    { }
    else
    {
        string fetchXML = entity.Attributes["fetchxml"].ToString();

        for (int i = 0; i < guidDictionnary.Count; i++)
        {
            var entry = guidDictionnary.ElementAt(i);

            if (fetchXML.Contains(entry.Key.ToString().ToUpperInvariant()))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(entity.Attributes["name"].ToString());
                oldValues++;
                if (destinationEnv.Equals("acc"))
                {
                    accValuesUpdated++;
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("BEFORE:");
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine(entity.Attributes["fetchxml"].ToString());
                    string query = entity.Attributes["fetchxml"].ToString();
                    query = query.Replace(entry.Key.ToString().ToUpperInvariant(), entry.Value.AccGuid.ToString().ToUpperInvariant());
                    entity.Attributes["fetchxml"] = query;
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("AFTER:");
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine(entity.Attributes["fetchxml"].ToString());
                }
                else
                {
                    prodValuesUpdated++;
                    string query = entity.Attributes["fetchxml"].ToString();
                    query = query.Replace(entry.Key.ToString().ToUpperInvariant(), entry.Value.ProdGuid.ToString().ToUpperInvariant());
                    entity.Attributes["fetchxml"] = query;
                }
                service.Update(entity);
            }

        }
    }

}
Console.WriteLine("{0} values to be updated. {1} shall be mapped to acceptance, {2} to prod. Total = {3} : {4}", oldValues, accValuesUpdated, prodValuesUpdated, total, retrievedViews.Entities.Count);
```

I see that the new value is corrected, but it does not get saved. I get no error while updating the record and publishing the changes in CRM does not help.

Any hint?

Comment: What is your `Console.Writeline` spitting out?

Comment: The FetchXML query. I see the query with the old GUID after "BEFORE" and the one with the updated GUID after "AFTER". Furthermore, when I check with a SQL query the views is shown as updated (the modifiedon field changes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your comments, it sounds like the value you're saving the entity as, is the value that you want it to be.  I'm guessing your issue is with not publishing your change.  If you don't publish it, it'll still give you the old value of the FetchXml I believe.

Try calling this method:

```cs
    PublishEntity(service, "savedquery");

    private void PublishEntity(IOrganizationService service, string logicalName)
    {
        service.Execute(new PublishXmlRequest()
        {
            ParameterXml = "<importexportxml>"
          + "    <entities>"
          + "        <entity>" + logicalName + "</entity>"
          + "    </entities>"
          + "</importexportxml>"
        });
    }
```